# Refastening a cabinet door

Tags: repair, doors, kitchens, screws, cabinets

A cabinet door in my kitchen detached from the cabinet- the screws are about 1/2" long and weren't enough to hold the door in place. The screws are short to keep them from poking out the back side of the wood and into the cabinet space.

My concern is that simply reattaching the door with the same screws in the same holes does nothing to keep the same thing from happening again. Is there something I can do to reinforce the holes or otherwise help increase the bite of the screws in the wood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the screw and hinge.  Break apart a wooden toothpick and place a few pieces in the existing hole.  For extra help, you can combine the pieces of toothpick with a little wood glue.  This will help hold them in place before the door is back on and also add extra stability once dry.  Then put the door back on and use the existing screw.  This should help hold it in place for a while.

In my experience, this will last a few years, and then when it gets loose again, do it again.  It will be like new.

Comment: You might want to use some wood glue with the toothpicks.

Comment: yes, glue would be a good idea.  added to post.